# plot cube in matlab

Tags: matlab, cube

I want to plot a cube of side length 10, that would be symmetrical from -5 to 5 and not -6 to 4.

```
xc=1; yc=1; zc=1;    % coordinated of the center
L=10;                 % cube size (length of an edge)
alpha=0.8;           % transparency (max=1=opaque)

X = [0 0 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0 0 1];
Y = [0 0 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 1 1; 0 1 1 1 1 1; 0 0 1 1 1 0];
Z = [0 0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 0; 1 1 1 0 1 1; 1 1 1 0 1 1];

C='blue';                  % unicolor

X = L*(X-0.5) + xc;
Y = L*(Y-0.5) + yc;
Z = L*(Z-0.5) + zc; 

fill3(X,Y,Z,C,'FaceAlpha',alpha);    % draw cube
axis equal
```

Comment: Can't you just set `xc`, `yc`, and `zc` to 0?

Answer (score 1):

I just set the center to `(0,0,0)` to get the desired result:

```
xc=0; yc=0; zc=0;    % coordinates of the center
```

[image]